# Manually Saving an Uncontrolled Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, download, gif

I am looking at a website with a canvas object on it.  The code for the canvas object in question is: (I've added an ID to it in the inspector to make it easier to grab)

```
<canvas data-item-id="handshake" data-is-animated="true" width="80" height="80" data-draw-state="invalid" id="customId" crossorigin="anonymous">(handshake)</canvas>
```

I want to download this canvas object as a gif (it's a small gif, and I want it. I MUST have it.), but no matter which method I try, I seem to run into cross-origin issues:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

or

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'captureStream' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Canvas is not origin-clean.
at <anonymous>:1:37
```

or even

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Note: I don't need to do this programatically.  I just can't seem to find the gif source for the canvas, and I don't control the code that is generating the canvas.  I just need a way to manually download it.  Pointers?

Comment: In google chrome I am able to just right click html canvases and choose "save image as..." to save whatever is displayed on the canvas as an image.